# Why is password recovery so slow for Whirlpool hash, when compared with others?

Tags: passwords, truecrypt

I'm just curious about why brute force takes so much longer on the Whirlpool hash than it does on the others, as you will see below:

```
Passcovery Suite Version 3.50 build 3653 x64
Benchmark
CPU [Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5020U CPU @ 2.20GHz]

Type: Microsoft® Word 2007
Protection: MS Office 2007, SHA1, 256-bit AES
Password recovery rate: 427 (453)

Type: OpenOffice v1.1
Protection: OpenOffice, PBKDF2/SHA1, 128-bit Blowfish
Password recovery rate: 10,654 (10,801)

Type: Blackberry 5.x backup
Protection: BlackBerry 5.x backup, PBKDF2/AES
Password recovery rate: 2,072,277 (2,082,185)

Type: WPA Handshake
Protection: WPA-PSK, PBKDF2/SHA1 HMAC/SHA1
Password recovery rate: 1,894 (1,900)

Type: RAR 3.x
Protection: RAR 3.x, SHA1, 128-bit AES
Password recovery rate: 383 (387)

Type: ZIP/Classic
Protection: ZIP proprietary algorithm, 96-bit
Password recovery rate: 26,890,751 (27,047,441)

Type: WinZip/AES
Protection: WinZip/AES, PBKDF2/SHA1, 256-bit AES
Password recovery rate: 12,891 (14,411)

Type: TrueCrypt volume
Protection: TrueCrypt volume header, PBKDF2/SHA-512/AES
Password recovery rate: 2,459 (2,476)

Type: TrueCrypt volume
Protection: TrueCrypt volume header, PBKDF2/RIPEMD-160/AES
Password recovery rate: 617 (627)

Type: TrueCrypt volume
Protection: TrueCrypt volume header, PBKDF2/Whirlpool/AES
Password recovery rate: 295 (302)

Type: Microsoft® Word 97
Protection: MS Office 97-2000, MD5, 40-bit RC4
Password recovery rate: 1,710,477 (1,703,046)

Type: Microsoft® Word 2003
Protection: MS Office XP-2003, SHA1, 128-bit RC4
Password recovery rate: 1,604,502 (1,602,161)

Type: Adobe® PDF
Protection: PDF /R 3, MD5, 128-bit RC4/AES
Password recovery rate: 125,753 (124,652)

Type: Adobe® PDF
Protection: PDF /R 6, SHA-256/384/512, 256-bit AES
Password recovery rate: 561 (563)


CPU frequency measured: 2195 Mhz

Raw results: 427, 10654, 2072277, 1894, 383, 26890751, 12891, 2459, 617, 295, 1710477, 1604502, 125753, 561
```

Also, one more question:

How much faster can I recover my password (20+ characters) from knowing nothing about it (it's been years since I last used it) using a GPU instead?

Comment: Note: For password hashing used for verification being slow is important. The current rule-of-thumb is 100ms per hash. This is usually obtained by iteration. There are also password hashing algorithms that are designed to use substantial memory in order to thwart GPUs, a current example is ALGO2. Encryption is a poor method to protect passwords and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary to recover a password.

Answer (score 3):

> how much faster can i recover my password (20+ characters) from
>   knowing nothing about it (it's been years since i last used it) using
>   a gpu instead?

According to this benchmark, [a *single* Nvidia Tesla V100 (the best GPU commercially available) will hit 94kH/s on that specific mode (search for 6231 on that page)](https://medium.com/@iraklis/running-hashcat-v4-0-0-in-amazons-aws-new-p3-16xlarge-instance-e8fab4541e9b) which is about 300x as fast as your CPU and of course you can just use multiple GPUs. For example on Amazon's cloud services, you can have up to 8 such GPUs per VM.

Note however, if you really used a random 20+ character password, there are at least $2^{94}$ possible passwords (if you have used 20 lower case characters only) and testing this amount of passwords is infeasible (and would require $2^{77}$ GPU-years).

> I'm just curious about why bruteforce takes so much longer on the
>   whirlpool hash than it does on the others

This is hard to answer. It may be that not a significant amount of effort has been invested in optimizing the Whirlpool implementations, because it's a somewhat rarely seen hash function. It may be that the huge amounts of table-lookups that Whirlpool apparently requires slow down the operations imensely compared to the register-fitting other hash functions.

Comment: Generally random character sequences are not used, rather lists of frequently used passwords order by frequency such as at [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords). Additionally some cracking software also fuzzes the passwords.